# Need help on apache2 permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server, raspberry-pi

This is what I'm trying to do: change the default directory of apache2 from /var/www/html to /media/pi/storage/root_folder/

I have followed this tutorial > https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Virtual_Hosts

under section virtual hosts, I created a test html at /home/pi/Desktop/ and it works because of correct permissions.

Now when I do the exact same thing at /media/pi/storage/root_folder/ and reload the webpage, I get forbidden error message, suggesting that I have permission issues on my hard drive.

Will something like this work?

```
sudo chown -R USER:USER /media/pi/storage/root_folder/
```

And finally, how do I get these permissions to be applied for any new subdirectories and files in the future so that I don't run into the same forbidden error ever again?

I appreciate any help, thanks guys..

Comment: I know because, only one thing changed in my setup, that is only the directory, and forbidden simply tells me that's it's a permission issue, I haven't gone in depth with it but I think it's a pretty safe assumption. Also, it's a dead giveaway if the test html worked but not the one in my hard drive.

Comment: Output of `ps aux | grep apache2` :                                                                                                
`root       469  0.0  0.4   7716  4044 ?        Ss   03:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start`
`www-data   470  0.0  0.3 230116  3500 ?        Sl   03:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start`
`www-data   471  0.0  0.3 230116  3500 ?        Sl   03:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start`
`pi         994  0.0  0.0   4344   552 pts/0    S+   03:27   0:00 grep --color=auto apache2`

Comment: And output of groups is: `pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev gpio i2c spi`

Comment: This has been solved in my other post at ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/986999/need-help-on-apache2-permissions-ive-tried-myself-im-not-lazy?noredirect=1#comment1589596_986999

Answer (score 0):

Yes, changing the ownership of the filesystem tree rooted in `/media/pi/storage/root_folder/` to (the user under which Apache Httpd runs, generally `apache`) should work as long as the user can access that filesystem tree (i.e. it must be able to "execute" the directories `media`, `pi` and `storage`.

However, if `selinux` is enable, the files may need to have additional permissions.

Run `selinuxenabled && echo enabled` to see whether it is enabled.

If so, run

```
chcon -vR --type=httpd_sys_content_t /media/pi/storage/root_folder
```

to change the SELinux context of the files under `/media/pi/storage/root_folder` (I'm not SELinux guru, but that works for me).

Comment: bash: selinuxenabled: command not found
 What else should I do?

Comment: Will something like `chgrp -R www-data /username/`
`chmod -R 2750 /username/`  work? Or something to do with the www-data group? Help me, I don't know what command to use, all I need is so that apache can access my hard drive located at /media/pi/storage/root_folder/ shouldln't be that hard, but I couldn't figure it out, I've been trying for a day now..

Comment: my permissions for root_folder in my hard drive is `drwxrwxr-x 10 pi   pi    4096 Dec 16 20:24 root_folder` and the /var/www/html/ folder is `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 16 21:33 html
`